# Python: Can not find local module

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-venv

For my PyQt5 project, the directory structure is like this:

```
|
|
|--app.py
|
|---ui_components
    |
    |--main_window.py
    |--toolbar.py
```

`app.py` is not *explicitly* importing `toolbar.py`, rather, it imports `main_window.py`. Now `main_window.py` imports `toolbar`. But when app.py is run, it throws an

> error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'toolbar'

**Code**

**`main_window.py`**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QDockWidget, QTextEdit
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from toolbar import init_toolbar


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Adding toolbar
        init_toolbar(self)

        # Create the dock widgets
        project_dock = QDockWidget("Project", self)
        dock2 = QDockWidget("Dock 2", self)
        plot_dock = QDockWidget("Plot", self)
        dock4 = QDockWidget("Dock 4", self)
        editor_dock = QDockWidget("Editor", self)

        # Set the dock widget features
        # dock1.setFeatures(QDockWidget.DockWidgetFloatable | QDockWidget.DockWidgetMovable)
        # dock2.setFeatures(QDockWidget.DockWidgetFloatable | QDockWidget.DockWidgetMovable)
        # dock3.setFeatures(QDockWidget.DockWidgetFloatable | QDockWidget.DockWidgetMovable)
        # dock4.setFeatures(QDockWidget.DockWidgetFloatable | QDockWidget.DockWidgetMovable)
        # dock5.setFeatures(QDockWidget.DockWidgetFloatable | QDockWidget.DockWidgetMovable)

        # Add widgets to the dock widgets
        

        # Add the dock widgets to the main window
        self.addDockWidget(1, project_dock)
        self.addDockWidget(1, dock2)
        self.addDockWidget(2, plot_dock)
        self.addDockWidget(2, dock4)

        # Set the central widget
        self.setCentralWidget(editor_dock)

        # Set the dock widget corners
        self.setCorner(Qt.TopLeftCorner, Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea)
        self.setCorner(Qt.TopRightCorner, Qt.RightDockWidgetArea)
        self.setCorner(Qt.BottomLeftCorner, Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea)
        self.setCorner(Qt.BottomRightCorner, Qt.RightDockWidgetArea)

        self.setWindowTitle("Grafing[dev]")
```

---

**`toolbar.py`**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QToolBar, QAction
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon


def init_toolbar(main_window):
    toolbar = QToolBar()
    main_window.addToolBar(toolbar)
```

---

**`app.py`**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from ui_components.main_window import MainWindow

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

1. The path of the module is absolutely correct. I am using VS code and CTRL+Clicking on the module name in `main_window.py` opens up the correct file.
2. If I place `app.py` inside `ui_components` then it perfectly works(of course after import statements are updated accordingly).

PS: I am using virtual env.

Comment: Change to `from .toolbar import init_toolbar` (notice the dot before `toolbar`). Imports are relative to the working dir, not the file.

Comment: @TheApache The error is about import structure, not the PyQt installation.

Comment: Changing to `from .toolbar import init_toolbar` did work. Thanks.